# merge two tiles of Worldclim data with gdal_merge.py - Nodata

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-merge

I am trying to merge two tiles of the worldclim data in geotiff format, which I want to subsequently work with in the raster package in R.

When I use gdal's gdal_merge.py script: *gdal_merge.py -v -o tmean1_06_16.tif tmean1_06.tif tmean1_16.tif*

I get a merged file, but it seems as if the oceans have all been set to 0. see pic
[image]

So I thought that the no data value is not set correctly when merging. Therefore I looked up the no data value in one of the original tiles with gdalinfo.

It seems the no data value is set to *NoData Value=-3.39999999999999996e+38*

So i tried to use that value when merging:
*gdal_merge.py -v -n -3.39999999999999996e+38 -o tmean1_06_16.tif tmean1_06.tif tmean1_16.tif*

But that results in a file that seems to either have lost all information or have a legend that is shifted so far, that every temperature value is set to the max. Everything is a uniform green now.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have figured it out.

If one resets the Nodata value in the original files to -9999 with:
*gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 tmean1_16.tif tmean1_16_error999.tif*

and then uses gdalmerge specifying both the input nodata value and the output nodatavalue:
*gdal_merge.py -v -n -9999 -a_nodata -9999 -o tmean1_06_16.tif tmean1_06_error999.tif tmean1_16_error999.tif*

Then everything looks ok:

[image]